# Preserving scroll position with react-router 1.0 when programmatically updating the url

Tags: react-router

I need to preserve the scroll position when updating the url with react-router 1.0

I have something like:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class Standard extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    history: React.PropTypes.object
  }

  someHandler(url) {
    this.context.history.pushState(null, url);
  }

  render() {


    return (
      <div>
        ... lots of content ...
        <div someEvent={someHandler.bind(this, '/some/url')}> 
            some content 
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This correctly updates the url, however it also resets the scroll position to the top, which I don't want as the new url reflects a scroll position in an infinitely scrolling list and the user has not really navigated anywhere.

How can I update the url whilst also maintaining scroll position? (Ideally I also wouldn't trigger a re-render as it is not needed)

In searching through react-router issues I found ignoreScrollBehavior which can be set on routes. However this does not work. I think this was a 0.13 feature and was removed for 1.0, but I can't find an alternative for 1.0.

I also can't update to react-router 2.0 at this time as I have other dependencies on 1.0

Comment: Can you create a simple exemple?

Answer (score 0):

By default, React Router doesn't do any management of scroll position – if you're seeing the scroll position change, that's likely because e.g. the route transition is changing the rendered height of the page. In that case, you just have to be careful about making sure you don't render a flash of empty content due to async handling.